# Generate custom attribute in XML from XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, schema, marshalling

I am trying to marshal to xml using JAXB.

*My Requirement*

if any elements value is null then the xml should have that element's attribute as **nullable="true"**.

I tried putting **minoccurs="1", nillable="true"** in XSD, but it gave me nil="true" in my xml, but I wanted to show as **nullable="true"** exactly in my xml.

```
     <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="itemName" type="xs:string" />
     <xs:element name="purchasedOn" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
     <xs:element name="amount" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
```

In my XML :

```
 <purchasedOn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you wanting the attribute to say that the element **can be** null or that it **is** null ?

Comment: nullable means that it's okay for that element to be null. It sounds like you will need to define your own bespoke attribute for this purpose. Can I ask, what's wrong with an empty element tag?

Comment: If you have a null attribute, what's going to be inside the element it belongs to if it can't be empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93671/discussion-between-kranthi-sama-and-kirstyannelouise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:complexType name="CustomDate">
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:date">
<xs:attribute name="nullable" type="xs:string">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```